# Library with CMake on windows

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I'm trying to run this code with CMake on windows 7:

```
add_library(xpl SHARED xpl.c)

if(WINDOWS)
    set(WIN_EXTRA_LIBS hulamemmgr)
endif(WINDOWS)

target_link_libraries(xpl
    ${WIN_EXTRA_LIBS}
    ${ALL_LIBS}
)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(xpl
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION 1.0.0
    SOVERSION 1
    INSTALL_NAME_DIR "${LIB_DEST_DIR}"
)

install(TARGETS xpl
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_DEST_DIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${LIB_DEST_DIR}
)
```

This CMakeList is inserted in a subdirectory and it is run after other CMakeList at higher level.  At the end I did not get any library.

The Variable `${LIB_DEST_DIR}` is right, xpl.c code is available in the same directory of CMakeList.

Is there any error? Why can I not get any library?  I run CMake-gui, first configure task then generate task.

Thanks
PR

Comment: Did you do a `make install`?  The `install` stuff in CMake only runs on a `make install`.

Comment: Have you built the project?  Running CMake only creates the Visual Studio solution file, or MinGW makefile, etc depending on which generator you chose.  It doesn't actually build the library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 commands.

1) Cmake -G "Generator name" -B"Dest path" -H"Source cmakelists.txt path"

2) Cmake --build "Dest path"